# Extraer texto de una imagen con tesseract

Tags: python, pytesseract, tesseract

Tengo el siguiente código para extraer texto de una imagen, pero me aparece el siguiente error al ejecutarlo:

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/Deteccion de Objetos/instalador/TextDetection-master/images/imgText_01.png")
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
result = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

print(result)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agustin, es curioso que el error mencione que no encuentre el idioma **eng**, ya que éste se instala por defecto. Repasemos la instalación:

1.- Se debe descargar e instalar `tesseract` desde
https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki
En mi caso, descargué **tesseract-ocr-w64-setup-v5.0.0-alpha.20200223.exe** para Windows de 64 bits.

2.- Por defecto `tesseract` funciona con reconocimiento en inglés, para descargar otro idioma usa https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Data-Files
Yo usé https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/raw/4.00/spa.traineddata, para idioma español.

Copiar el archivo **spa.traineddata** en ..\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata\

3.- Agregar la carpeta ..\Tesseract-OCR al PATH de Windows.

4.- Probar la instalación desde la consola cmd con el comando `tesseract --list-langs`.
Deben salir los idiomas instalados, en mi caso retorna:

> eng
>   osd
>   spa

Teniendo eso, ya debes poder hacer tus pruebas. Con tu código no tengo ningún problema:

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("imagen_con_texto.png")
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"mi_ruta\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
result = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
```

Con el  método `image_to_string`, puedes usar el parámetro `lang="spa"`, para usar la detección en idioma español u otro que tengas instalado. Si por ejemplo además de español, tienes francés, puedes usar:

`result = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang="eng+spa+fra")`

Con eso le estás dando al reconocedor la capacidad de detectar texto en inglés, español y francés, en la misma llamada.

Answer (score 0):

Probé tu código y me funciona bien.

Mmmm parece como si algo estaría mal instalado, podria sugerirte revisar:

1. [Instalación tsseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki#installation)
2. [Download tsseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Downloads)

Answer (score 0):

Tesseract puede recibir varios parámetros de entrada cómo el idioma del texto, estructura del documento, etc. Por defecto toma el idioma inglés 'eng', los datos de entrenamiento para detectar idiomas específicos se encuentran dentro de la ruta donde tienes el ejecutable.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dentro de la carpeta tessdata debería estar el archivo eng.traineddata, correspondiente al idioma inglés. Si no está, te recomiendo que lo descargues desde el repositorio de tesseract.
[Git tessdata](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata)
Aplica para cualquier idioma.