# Como obtener texto de una imagen?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, pytesseract

Estoy tratando de obtener el texto de una imagen que esta contenida en una etiqueta, la medida de la etiqueta es mas o menos de 5mm x 80mm, hay un codigo de barras a la izquierda y el texto a la derecha o viceverza , en otras etiquetas el texto esta abajo del codigo de barras.

Tengo el siguiente codigo en el cual aplico unos filtros y obtengo el contorno de las letras o numeros pero ahora quiero aplicar OCR a la imagen ya procesada y ahi estoy atorado, les dejo mi codigo.

```html
import cv2
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
image = cv2.imread('124610.jpeg')

placa =[]
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(3,3),0)
canny = cv2.Canny(gray,150,200)
canny = cv2.dilate(canny,None,iterations = 1)
cnts,_ = cv2.findContours(canny,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng')
#print('Texto:',text)
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    
    if  area > 1000:
        print('Area=',area)
        cv2.drawContours(image,cnts,-1,(0,255,0),2)
       
cv2.imshow('Image',image)
cv2.imshow('Canny',canny)
cv2.moveWindow('Image',45,10)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Esto es lo que obtengo con el codigo anterior, el texto de la imagen original es CO023045
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el foro encontre esta otra pregunta similar pero al aplicar lo de aqui me cambia la O por 0 y el 0 por @ en algunos casos Pregunta: [Extraer texto de una imagen con tesseract](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/313055/extraer-texto-de-una-imagen-con-tesseract) esto me muestra C0@23045

EDITADO: Esta una imagen de la etiqueta commpleta el texto varia en todas las etiquetas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podrías subir la imagen para poder hacer unas pruebas?

Comment: Ya puse una imagen completa de la etiqueta @LucasDamian

Comment: Pregunta, ¿no sale mejor leer el código de barra? Está en formato **Code 128** y se lee `C003N5C`

Comment: En realidad quiero leer ambos, solo que voy por partes ya que en ocaciones lo que tiene el codigo de barras y el texto no coinciden y mi idea es leer cada uno y comparar ambos valores, tienes algun ejemplo de lo que comentas? @aeportugal

Comment: Ya he conseguido leer el texto y el codigo de barras solo que tengo dos scripts(uno para leer el codigo de barras y otro para el texto) y siendo sinceros es la primera vez que uso python para programar, estoy intentando hacer un solo script pero estoy batallando con la estructura y la sintaxis, si alguien me pudiera apoyar a crear un solo script para publicar el codigo en la pregunta :)

Answer (score 0):

Las cosas importantes que debes tener en cuenta son:

- Usar el blanco para el fondo y el negro para la fuente de los caracteres.
- Seleccionar el modo psm adecuado. En este caso, el psm mode número 7 procura tratar la imagen como una sola línea de texto.
- Usar la configuración tessedit_char_whitelist para especificar los caracteres deseados en tu búsqueda de texto. En este caso todo el abecedario en mayúsculas y todos los números.

Con todo eso en mente, este es el código:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'
img = cv2.imread('a.jpg')
grayImage = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(_, blackWhiteImage) = cv2.threshold(grayImage, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
data = pytesseract.image_to_data(blackWhiteImage, config="-c tessedit_char_whitelist=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 --psm 7")
originalImage = cv2.cvtColor(blackWhiteImage, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

text = []
for z, a in enumerate(data.splitlines()):
    if z != 0:
        a = a.split()
        if len(a) == 12:
            x, y = int(a[6]), int(a[7])
            w, h = int(a[8]), int(a[9])
            cv2.rectangle(originalImage, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 1)
            cv2.putText(originalImage, a[11], (x, y - 2), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 1)
            text.append(a[11]);

print("Text result: \n", text)
cv2.imshow('Image result', originalImage)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Y el resultado:

[image: Imagen resultado]

En mi experiencia el pre-processado es clave para la buena detección asi como filtrar solo los caracteres que quieres buscar. Casi nunca obtengo un texto perfecto en mis aplicaciones, mas si puedo filtrar o comparar este texto con lo que deseo encontrar para determinar si es el deseado. En tu caso, compara el texto reconocido con el encontrado con el código de barras teniendo en cuenta un margen de error de uno o dos caracteres.

Puedes tratar de mejorar los resultados siguiendo esta guia:

[Tesseract -Improving the quality of the output](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html)